Button visual state not working for Normal and Pressed states
Having this code:
<Button Text="CLICK ME"
        TextColor="White"
        TextTransform="Uppercase"
        FontAttributes="Bold"
        BackgroundColor="#58cc02"
        WidthRequest="120"
        HeightRequest="50"
        CornerRadius="15">

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Shadow">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Shadow Brush="#58a700"
                                    Offset="0,5"
                                    Radius="1" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Shadow">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Shadow Opacity="0" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="TranslationY"
                            Value="5" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

</Button>

The expected behaviour is that in the Normal state the button would have the shadow below it, when the button is pressed the shadow would disappear and the button would translate downward.
I am trying it on windows and the Shadow is not shown in both States and also when I release the button is still traslated downward.

Have you tried moving your shadow to a style and having the VisualStateManager activate the appropriate style?

Possibly related https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/19560

@StephenQuan Yes, doesn't work.

@Cfun It's not only a shadow problem, also the TranslationY does not change.

The problem are the default Style setters that are automatically created along with the project with path: Resources\Styles\Styles.xaml.
Deleting those default styles it works fine, so maybe there is a problem with the overwrite of the styles.
